# If $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix, how to obtain the decomposition $\Sigma = \Sigma^{1/2}(\Sigma^{1/2})^T$ from Cholesky Decompositon?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, matrix-decomposition

I read somewhere that if $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix, one can obtain the decomposition $\Sigma = \Sigma^{1/2}(\Sigma^{1/2})^T$ from Cholesky Decompositon. However, I am confused how because Cholesky decomposition requires an upper and lower triangular matrix. How can the square root here for upper and lower triangular, or can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\Sigma^{-1}$ is a positive definite matrix, there is a lower triangular, nonsingular matrix $C$ such that

$$C^T\Sigma^{-1}C = I$$

Hence,
 $$I = I^{-1} = (C^T\Sigma^{-1}C)^{-1} =  C^{-1} \Sigma (C^T)^{-1} \\ \implies CC^T = CIC^T = CC^{-1} \Sigma (C^T)^{-1}C^T = \Sigma.$$

For example, for the $2 \times 2$ case,

$$\Sigma = \pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \\ \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2} \\  \Sigma^{-1} = \frac{1}{1 - \rho^2}\pmatrix{\sigma_1^{-2} & -\rho\sigma_1^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} \\ -\rho \sigma_1^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} & \sigma_2^{-2}}.$$

$$C = \pmatrix{ \sigma_1 & 0 \\ \rho \sigma_2  & \sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
.$$

Comment: Thanks, can I ask how you get the first result of the existence of a lower triangular nonsingular $C$? Is it from the spectral theorem?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) showing the algorithm to obtain Cholesky  decomposition for any symmetric, positive definite matrix.  As you can see from the example it all works.

Comment: I see, so you are saying that: $C^T\Sigma^{-1}C = I \implies \Sigma^{-1} = CC^T$ which is the classic form of Cholesky. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I recall, and that transformation is the key to many useful results. The square root symbol is a convention in this case.  Not the literal square root $\Sigma = BB$.

Comment: From Wikipedia on matrix square root.: "The Cholesky factorization provides another particular example of square root, which should not be confused with the unique non-negative square root."